# How to access controls of dynamically added user controls in a panel in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a panel which has multiple dynamically added user controls (all the same) and I need to see if a checkbox is checked and what the label.text is in each of these controls. Not sure how I would get these values?

This is where the user controls are being added to the panel

```
private void Employee_Add_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> VehicleTypes = DAL.LicenseDAL.GetAllVehicleTypes();

        foreach (string Vehicle in VehicleTypes)
        {
            User_Controls.Vehicle_Bar VTB = new Vehicle_Bar(Vehicle);
            pnlVehicleChecks.Controls.Add(VTB);
        }
    }
```

This is the user control (which is literally just a label and checkbox)

```
public partial class Vehicle_Bar : UserControl
{
    public string Vehicle = "";

    public Vehicle_Bar(string vehicle)
    {
        Vehicle = vehicle;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Vehicle_Bar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblType.Text = Vehicle;
    }
}
```

All of these check-boxes are for a vehicle license for an employee, depending on what check boxes are checked depends what vehicle they will be allowed to drive

Comment: You can give `onclick` event for your `usercontrol` in form. Within `foreach` loop in your `form` declare `onclick` event for the `usercontrol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the retrieval of checkbox data inside the UserControl and store it in a publicly accessible data object

```
public class VehicleInfo
{
    public bool allowdrive {get; set; }
    public string vehicle {get; set; }
}

public partial class Vehicle_Bar : UserControl
{   
    public VehicleInfo vehicleInfo;

    public Vehicle_Bar(string vehicle)
    {
        vehicleInfo = new VehicleInfo(){
            vehicle = vehicle,
            allowdrive = false
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Vehicle_Bar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblType.Text = vehicleInfo.vehicle;
    }

    //Handle checkbox click event to set the value of "allowdrive"
}
```

The combined data of the string and the checkbox are stored in the object vehicleInfo, which can be accessed using an instance of the UserControl Vehicle_Bar

example :

```
Console.WriteLine(VTB.vehicleInfo.allowdrive);
```